# Aligning TextView's text with another TextView

Tags: android, button, textview, alignment

See picture below (or https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbHcQ.png). I'd like to have a button's text start at the same x position as that of a TextView that precedes it. The tricky part is that the button's text is horizontally centered with respect to the button.

In this example, Foo's left is on the same vertical guide as Lorem's left.

I looked at the available API on TextView and the layout returned by TextView.getLayout().

- getLineStart() is the number of chars from the beginning of the line so that doesn't help.
- The closest I think is getParagraphLeft(), but that's the offset between the TextView's left edge and the parent container, it seems. I tested by adding a paddingLeft to the TextView but getParagraphLeft still returned 0

My last resort is to have the TextView inside a FrameLayout. Set a margin on the TextView so getParagraphLeft returns a non-zero number. The click listener is set on the FrameLayout instead. The rest is handled via custom onLayout logic.

I'm hoping this kind of UI is a solved problem. Maybe I'm missing something obvious....

[image: sample_ux]

Comment: Does the attached image not show up? Try this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbHcQ.png

Comment: Thanks! Edited my question